# OneSignal - Popup Notifications not showing in Android React Native

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I am unable to view [Popup Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qroc.jpg) on android app created via react-native using OneSignal. I am able to view it in System tray. The eventListener `onReceived` function of OneSignal is also called and I can see the notification (only in the system tray) and also able to hear the *ding* sound, but notification popup did not show.

My code where I configure OneSignal in the main container:

```
OneSignal.init("ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID");
OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2);
OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', (payload) => store.dispatch(Actions.savePushTokenLocal(payload)));
OneSignal.addEventListener('received', (payload) => store.dispatch(Actions.notificationReceived(payload)));
OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', (payload) => store.dispatch(Actions.notificationOpened(payload)));
OneSignal.configure()
```

I need to be able to view the notification popup when the notification is received, but I am unable to. I have tried almost everything that the documentation has to offer, but all in vain.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the time of writing this it seems like it there have been issues on this. On the iOS initialization docs (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk) it states "At the present time, none of these settings are available in the Android SDK." which below refers to setting the kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption parameter. I assuming this is causing your problem and hopefully available in the future. The best solution may be to set the inFocusDisplaying to 0 and present a custom notification by animating a component into view for a set time when a notification is received. That way you have the ability to customize how the notification displays and behaves.